# Rails: Show form from different model in a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, partial

I have a `location` model and a `post` model. I want to allow the user to create new `posts` from the `index` page of the `location` model. How do I do that? I tried rendering the `post` `new.html.erb` as a partial in `location` `index.html.erb`, but this leads to errors as `post` `new.html.erb` references the `@post` variable.

How should I accomplish this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try something like this

```
LocationController

def index
  @location = Location.find(:all)
  @post = Post.new
end
```

Now ur location view would have access to the instance variable `@post`. Render a partial using that

```
render :partial => 'posts/post', :object => @post
```

Comment: +1, ..or, in a way similar to what Allesklar proposes: use `Post.new` instead of the variable, but this depends on the view: the variable may be 'hardcoded' there.

Answer (score 3):

You can start the form like this:

```
<%= form_for Post.new do ... %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a `@post` variable in your action in the LocationsController.

Comment: That gives me this error: `Expected /home/eyekandy/rails_apps/eyekandy/app/controllers/locations_controller.rb to define LocationsController`

Comment: Then you have a **syntax error** in your code. Could you show the code of your action? I assume that you edited only the action, but the error may be somewhere else - maybe you accidentally removed some character?